# Kotlin numerical parser cannot work with `10` and gives E+ when multiplying with 10

Tags: kotlin, parsing, bigdecimal

Expected output: `3650` 
I have tested my code with many numerical expressions, all gives correct answers. **Only 10 is creating all the problem**

My `MParser.kt` file

```kotlin
package com.parser

import java.math.BigDecimal
import java.math.RoundingMode

class MParser(private var mainExp: String) {
    var originalExp: String = ""
    init {
        println(mainExp)
        mainExp = mainExp.dePrettify()
        originalExp = mainExp
    }

    fun calc(): String {
        calcD()
        calcM()
        rearrange()
        calcA()
        calcMi()
        if (mainExp==originalExp)
            return "Hello"
        return mainExp
    }

    private fun dividable(): MutableList<String> {
        val divisible = mutableListOf<String>()
        Regex("(\\d+\\.*\\d*)(/+(\\d+\\.*\\d*))+").apply {
            this.findAll(mainExp).toMutableList().forEach {
                divisible.add(it.value)
            }
        }
        return divisible
    }

    private fun calcD() {
        dividable().forEach {
            mainExp = mainExp.replace(it, divide(it).toString())
        }
    }


    private fun divide(exp: String): BigDecimal {
        val num = toDoubleMutableList(exp.split("/").toMutableList())
        while (num.size > 1) {
            val dividend = num[0]
            val divisor = num[1]
            val quotient = dividend.divide(divisor, 3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
            num[0] = quotient
            num.removeAt(1)
        }
        return num[0]
    }

    private fun multiplies(): MutableList<String> {
        val multiplies = mutableListOf<String>()
        Regex("(\\d+\\.*\\d*)(\\*+(\\d+\\.*\\d*))+").apply {
            this.findAll(mainExp).toMutableList().forEach {
                multiplies.add(it.value)
            }
        }
        return multiplies
    }

    private fun calcM() {
        multiplies().forEach {
            mainExp = mainExp.replace(it, multiply(it).toString())
        }
    }

    private fun multiply(exp: String): BigDecimal {
        val num = toDoubleMutableList(exp.split("*").toMutableList())
        while (num.size > 1) {
            val factor1 = num[0]
            val factor2 = num[1]
            val product = factor1 * factor2
            num[0] = product
            num.removeAt(1)
        }
        return num[0]
    }


    private fun addable(): MutableList<String> {
        // 5*9*69/3/99+45-78*6/3/2-89 = sample
        val multiplies = mutableListOf<String>()
        Regex("(\\d+\\.*\\d*)(\\++(\\d+\\.*\\d*))+").apply {
            this.findAll(mainExp).toMutableList().forEach {
                multiplies.add(it.value)
            }
        }
        return multiplies
    }

    private fun calcA() {
        addable().forEach {
            mainExp = mainExp.replace(it, add(it).toString())
        }
    }

    private fun add(exp: String): BigDecimal {
        val num = toDoubleMutableList(exp.split("+").toMutableList())
        while (num.size > 1) {
            val addend1 = num[0]
            val addend2 = num[1]
            val sum = addend1 + addend2
            num[0] = sum
            num.removeAt(1)
        }
        return num[0]
    }

    private fun minusable(): MutableList<String> {
        // 5*9*69/3/99+45-78*6/3/2-89 = sample
        val multiplies = mutableListOf<String>()
        Regex("(\\d+\\.*\\d*)(-+(\\d+\\.*\\d*))+").apply {
            this.findAll(mainExp).toMutableList().forEach {
                multiplies.add(it.value)
            }
        }
        return multiplies
    }

    private fun calcMi() {
        minusable().forEach {
            mainExp = mainExp.replace(it, minus(it).toString())
        }
    }

    fun minus(exp: String): BigDecimal {
        val num = toDoubleMutableList(exp.split("-").toMutableList())
        while (num.size > 1) {
            val addend1 = num[0]
            val addend2 = num[1]
            val sum = addend1 - addend2
            num[0] = sum
            num.removeAt(1)
        }
        return num[0]
    }

    /*
    Utility -- Methods
     */

    private fun rearrange() {
        val subtracts = mutableListOf<String>()
        Regex("(-(\\d+\\.*\\d*))").apply {
            this.findAll(mainExp).forEach {
                subtracts.add(it.value)
            }
        }
        subtracts.forEach {
            mainExp = mainExp.replaceFirst(it, "")
            mainExp += it
        }
        if (mainExp.startsWith("+"))
            mainExp = mainExp.replaceFirst("+", "")
    }

    fun isParenthesisValid(): Boolean {
        var valid = true
        val stack = ArrayDeque<Char>()

        for (symb in mainExp) {
            if (symb == '(' || symb == '[' || symb == '{')
                stack.addLast(symb)
            else if (symb == ')' || symb == ']' || symb == '}') {
                if (stack.isEmpty())
                    valid = false
                else {
                    val i = stack.removeLast()
                    if (i == '(' && symb != ')' || i == '{' && symb != '}' || i == '[' && symb != ']')
                        valid = false
                } //end else
            }
            println("stack: $stack")
        } //end for-loop
        if (stack.isNotEmpty())
            valid = false
        return valid
    }

    private fun String.dePrettify(): String {
        return this.replace(" ", "").replace("÷", "/").replace("×", "*")
    }

    fun optimize(exp: String): String {
        return exp.replace(" ", "").replace("÷", "/").replace("×", "*")
    }
}

fun toDoubleMutableList(list: MutableList<String>): MutableList<BigDecimal> {
    val tempList = mutableListOf<BigDecimal>()
    for (i in list) {
        val b = BigDecimal(i.toDouble().toString()).stripTrailingZeros()
        tempList.add(b)
    }
    return tempList
}
```

When I do `val value = try {MParser("365*10").calc()} catch (e: NumberFormatException) {"Error"}` in another `.kt file`, I am getting `value = 3.65E+3`

 **How is the E+ appearing?**

I have debugged the code.
[image: debug-image]

I think the problem starts from `calcMi()`. Check it once as I cannot understand what to do.

**Expressions that I have tested and were coorect:**

```
    //whole numbers
    val wexp0 = "12 + 4 - 8 ÷ 2 × 3".optimize() //4
    val wexp1 = "7 - 5 + 14 ÷ 2 + 6".optimize() //15
    val wexp2 = "37 - 6 × 4 + 32 ÷ 8".optimize() //17
    val wexp3 = "64 - 48 ÷ 6 × 4 + 8".optimize() //40

    //decimal numbers
    val dexp0 = "5*9*69/3/99+45-78*6/3/2-89-4/5+62.2/2/4"
    val dexp1 = "-5+4-4+1-78+86-21+9+5-5-1+9.787-2+1000"
    val dexp2 = "0.2 + 1.3 - 0.4 × 1.5".optimize() //0.9
    val dexp3 = "0.3 × 0.4 - 2.4 ÷ 6 + 1.2 × 4".optimize() //4.52
    val dexp4 = "0.72 ÷ 1.2 + 3.5 × 4.2 - 1.6".optimize() //13.7
    val dexp5 = "9.2 + 3.5 - 4.9 - 3.5 ÷ 0.7 × 1.2".optimize() //1.8
    val dexp6 = "95.01 × 1.2 - 2.4 ÷ 2".optimize() //4.812
```

But as you can see I never used 10 in any of the above. And suddenly when I used 10, I spotted the issue.

Please see the **debug-image** carefully. 10 gets converted to `1E+1` even before the multiplication is done.

Comment: `3.65E+3 == 3650`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Please tell in little details, as I am not very good at kotlin.

Comment: This is not really Kotlin: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Ok I understand. Actually I am a school student,  not yet covered that `scientific notation`.  But anyways, why will it be shown for such a small number. 3650 is not very big, that  `scientific notation` is required.

Comment: Really bizarre, why will 3650 need E+.

Comment: I think there is some problem with `Bigdecimal`. Though I am not expert, I am just guessing it.

Comment: @DronBhattacharya There's no problem with `BigDecimal`. If you do `BigDecimal.toPlainString()` you get the standard notation.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Please check the question again as I have made some `edits`.

Comment: Well, you explicitly requested this behavior by using `stripTrailingZeros()`. As documentation says: "For example, stripping the trailing zeros from the BigDecimal value 600.0 (...) yields 6E2".

Comment: I don't see the problem. The value of the `BigDecimal` is correct. It's only a matter of how it's presented, and you can freely choose how to present it.

Comment: @broot I just removed the `stripTrailingZeros()`. Now I am getting `3650.00`. But then, How can I remove the `.00` part as I don't want it in the output without manipulating the `String`. I want to do it only if there is zeros, not if there is some numbers.

Comment: @broot Why is this happening only with `10`. As in my question, see all the expressions that I tested. The result is just beside each expression

Comment: Because you were lucky ;-) It happens only if there are trailing zeroes in the input data, because only then you use `toDoubleMutableList()`. It is not that easy to trigger by accident, but you can get it e.g. by: `2*5+2*5`.

Comment: @broot Yes, `2*5+2*5` does the same thing. But now that I have removed `stripTrailingZeros()` , how can I **get rid of the trailing zeros without `String` manipulation**.

Comment: @broot is it possible without `String` manipulations. Also, Can you create a answer for this question with optimized code. As I think, I have done some unnecessary conversions. And used `BigDecimal`. **Basically, can the code be better than What it is now?**

Comment: What is the reason you convert string to double and then back to string when constructing `BigDecimal`? What if you initialize it just by: `BigDecimal(i)`? It should fix your cases with `10`. Does it break other examples?

Comment: @broot Now I have removed the `decimal conversion` and everything is working fine and as expected. But I think I did the conversion due to some reason. But I am not able to remember. But I tested the code without  `decimal conversion`  and there is no problem.

Comment: @broot I have done **`val b = BigDecimal(i).stripTrailingZeros()` and got the result `3.65E+3`**

Comment: @broot can you see it again. Even better, if you run the code and suggest changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved the problem.

I have changed all the return types of `minus()`, `add()`, `multiply()`, `divide()` to **string** instead of keeping it`BigDecimal`.

Each of these methods were returning `BigDecimal` due to which I was getting the E+ in my output. But I observed that all the returned values from these methods were finally added to a `String`

So after the calculations I applied `toPlainString()` to the `BigDecimal` that were returned.

By doing this, the E+ does not appear in the output and I also don't have to manage the trailing zeros one by one.

### **New code**

```kotlin
package com.parser

import java.math.BigDecimal
import java.math.RoundingMode

class MParser(private var mainExp: String) {
    var originalExp: String = ""
    init {
        println(mainExp)
        mainExp = mainExp.dePrettify()
        originalExp = mainExp
    }

    fun calc(): String {
        calcD()
        calcM()
        rearrange()
        calcA()
        calcMi()
        if (mainExp==originalExp)
            return "Hello"
        return mainExp
    }

    private fun dividable(): MutableList<String> {
        val divisible = mutableListOf<String>()
        Regex("(\\d+\\.*\\d*)(/+(\\d+\\.*\\d*))+").apply {
            this.findAll(mainExp).toMutableList().forEach {
                divisible.add(it.value)
            }
        }
        return divisible
    }

    private fun calcD() {
        dividable().forEach {
            mainExp = mainExp.replace(it, divide(it).toString())
        }
    }


    private fun divide(exp: String): String {
        val num = toDoubleMutableList(exp.split("/").toMutableList())
        while (num.size > 1) {
            val dividend = num[0]
            val divisor = num[1]
            val quotient = dividend.divide(divisor, 3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
            num[0] = quotient
            num.removeAt(1)
        }
        return num[0].toPlainString()
    }

    private fun multiplies(): MutableList<String> {
        val multiplies = mutableListOf<String>()
        Regex("(\\d+\\.*\\d*)(\\*+(\\d+\\.*\\d*))+").apply {
            this.findAll(mainExp).toMutableList().forEach {
                multiplies.add(it.value)
            }
        }
        return multiplies
    }

    private fun calcM() {
        multiplies().forEach {
            mainExp = mainExp.replace(it, multiply(it).toString())
        }
    }

    private fun multiply(exp: String): String {
        val num = toDoubleMutableList(exp.split("*").toMutableList())
        while (num.size > 1) {
            val factor1 = num[0]
            val factor2 = num[1]
            val product = factor1 * factor2
            num[0] = product.stripTrailingZeros()
            num.removeAt(1)
        }
        return num[0].toPlainString()
    }


    private fun addable(): MutableList<String> {
        // 5*9*69/3/99+45-78*6/3/2-89 = sample
        val multiplies = mutableListOf<String>()
        Regex("(\\d+\\.*\\d*)(\\++(\\d+\\.*\\d*))+").apply {
            this.findAll(mainExp).toMutableList().forEach {
                multiplies.add(it.value)
            }
        }
        return multiplies
    }

    private fun calcA() {
        addable().forEach {
            mainExp = mainExp.replace(it, add(it).toString())
        }
    }

    private fun add(exp: String): String {
        val num = toDoubleMutableList(exp.split("+").toMutableList())
        while (num.size > 1) {
            val addend1 = num[0]
            val addend2 = num[1]
            val sum = addend1 + addend2
            num[0] = sum
            num.removeAt(1)
        }
        return num[0].toPlainString()
    }

    private fun minusable(): MutableList<String> {
        // 5*9*69/3/99+45-78*6/3/2-89 = sample
        val multiplies = mutableListOf<String>()
        Regex("(\\d+\\.*\\d*)(-+(\\d+\\.*\\d*))+").apply {
            this.findAll(mainExp).toMutableList().forEach {
                multiplies.add(it.value)
            }
        }
        return multiplies
    }

    private fun calcMi() {
        minusable().forEach {
            mainExp = mainExp.replace(it, minus(it).toString())
        }
    }

    fun minus(exp: String): String {
        val num = toDoubleMutableList(exp.split("-").toMutableList())
        while (num.size > 1) {
            val addend1 = num[0]
            val addend2 = num[1]
            val sum = addend1 - addend2
            num[0] = sum
            num.removeAt(1)
        }
        return num[0].toPlainString()
    }

    /*
    Utility -- Methods
     */

    private fun rearrange() {
        val subtracts = mutableListOf<String>()
        Regex("(-(\\d+\\.*\\d*))").apply {
            this.findAll(mainExp).forEach {
                subtracts.add(it.value)
            }
        }
        subtracts.forEach {
            mainExp = mainExp.replaceFirst(it, "")
            mainExp += it
        }
        if (mainExp.startsWith("+"))
            mainExp = mainExp.replaceFirst("+", "")
    }

    fun isParenthesisValid(): Boolean {
        var valid = true
        val stack = ArrayDeque<Char>()

        for (symb in mainExp) {
            if (symb == '(' || symb == '[' || symb == '{')
                stack.addLast(symb)
            else if (symb == ')' || symb == ']' || symb == '}') {
                if (stack.isEmpty())
                    valid = false
                else {
                    val i = stack.removeLast()
                    if (i == '(' && symb != ')' || i == '{' && symb != '}' || i == '[' && symb != ']')
                        valid = false
                } //end else
            }
            println("stack: $stack")
        } //end for-loop
        if (stack.isNotEmpty())
            valid = false
        return valid
    }

    private fun String.dePrettify(): String {
        return this.replace(" ", "").replace("÷", "/").replace("×", "*")
    }

    fun optimize(exp: String): String {
        return exp.replace(" ", "").replace("÷", "/").replace("×", "*")
    }
}

fun toDoubleMutableList(list: MutableList<String>): MutableList<BigDecimal> {
    val tempList = mutableListOf<BigDecimal>()
    for (i in list) {
        val b = BigDecimal(i).stripTrailingZeros()
        tempList.add(b)
    }
    return tempList
}
```